# Can't assign multiple line variables in R

Tags: r, variables, variable-assignment

I'm currenty trying to learn R and I have encountered a probably stupid problem, but I can't find a solution

I use RStudio, and when I try to assign a variable, I can assign a single line.
For example, if I try to run (I select all the lines and click the "Run" button) this code

```
age_survived <- summarise(group_by(train, Age, Survived), count=n())
    age_survived[which(age_survived$Survived==1), ] 
    rename(age_survived, "n_survived"="count")
```

It runs the lines separately and assign the variable "age_survived" to the first line only

So I tried to write the code like this

```
 age_survived <- {
    summarise(group_by(train, Age, Survived), count=n())
    age_survived[which(age_survived$Survived==1), ] 
    rename(age_survived, "n_survived"="count")
 }
```

But in this way I obtain this error

> Error: object 'age_survived' not found

The only way the code works is this

```
age_survived <- summarise(group_by(train, Age, Survived), count=n())
age_survived <- age_survived[which(age_survived$Survived==1), ] 
age_survived <- rename(age_survived, "n_survived"="count")
```

I don't think this is the way to do it, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Actually, that is the way to do it. Well, one way anyways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Pipes](https://www.r-statistics.com/2014/08/simpler-r-coding-with-pipes-the-present-and-future-of-the-magrittr-package/) might be what you're looking for. 
This code should work on the [train.csv](https://www.kaggle.com/c/titanic/data) Data which you're supposedly using.

```
age_survived <- summarise(group_by(train, Age, Survived), count=n()) %>%
  filter(Survived == 1) %>%
  rename("n_survived" = "count")
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works! I already knew pipes, but I didn't really understand how they work, now is clearer